# HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html

Tags: html, tomcat, http-status-code-404, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to run HTML file on Alfresco on folder `(alfrescodir)/tomcat/webapps`.

I try to run `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html`, but I got the error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html
type Status report

message /alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html

description The requested resource is not available.
```

How can I solve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
The files were in the wrong folder. The right folder would be: (alfrescodir)/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/ .